# select only name by maximal value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a request

```
select
    w.Departament_Id, avg(w.Salary) as avgSal,
    dep.Name as Name
from
    Employee w
join
    Departament dep
on
    dep.Id = w.Departament_Id 
group by
    w.Departament_Id,
    dep.Name
```

this request retuns a table contains all avg salary for each departament. Next the target is to select `Name` of departament with a maximal avgSal value.
How to solve it?

Comment: Add  `order by avgSal desc` and take the first entry. Depending on your DB engine this can be done with `top 1` or `limit 1` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sort by the aggregate and take the top 1:

```
select TOP 1
    w.Departament_Id, 
    avg(w.Salary) as avgSal,
    dep.Name as Name
from Employee w
join Departament dep
    on dep.Id = w.Departament_Id 
group by
    w.Departament_Id,
    dep.Name
ORDER BY avg(w.Salary) DESC
```

The syntax may be slightly different depending on your server software (some will allow `ORDER BY avgSal`, some will not; some will use `LIMIT` instead of `TOP`), but that's the general idea.